# SSIS package fails but SQL Server Agent marks success

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-agent

I have a SQL Server Agent job with two steps:

1. Executes an SSIS package with a *task* for importing a CSV and another *task* for sending an email saying that the import was successful. The step's *On Failure action* is set to *Quit the job reporting failure*. The *package source* is `File System`.
2. WIth tsql, updates a table saying that DTS package executed correctly.

When I run the dtsx package manually, the job fails with the import and the email is never sent.

When SQL Server Agent executes the job, it says that the first step ran successfully (the package) and then runs the 2nd step which updates the table. The email is not sent, so that's why I know it failed, but the table is updated.

Why doesn't SQL Server Agent reflect that the SSIS Job failed?

`[SSISDB].[catalog].[executions]` is empty and returns 0 rows.

The SQL Server Agent job history says that the job was successful.

Comment: Do you have the Agent task set to continue to the next task, regardless of success/failure? Have you checked the SSISDB logs to see if the package *actually* failed. If it did, there'll be errors. There isn't nearly enough information for us to help you here; you need to debug first.

Comment: *"`[SSISDB].[catalog].[executions]` is empty and returns 0 rows."* Are you executing the package via SSISDB? It's presumed you are, as SSISDB is *significantly* better than the old deployment methods.